# Map method use instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to change my for loop with .map method of jquery.
But I am not getting the output which I use to get in for-loop.

This is my actual loop that get the perfect data in the form of array.

```
var yourArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < marray.length; i++) {
    mId = marray[i].id;
    yourArray.push(mId);
}
```

same thing I tried using .map()

```
idArr = marray.map(function(row) {
                return row[i].id;
            });
```

But the actual array output is not coming.

Comment: This is just JavaScript, no jQuery.

Comment: Your code above shows the use of JavaScript's [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) not jQuery's [**jQuery.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: just `row.id` (drop the i)

Comment: @putvande: OP explicitly asked for jQuery `.map()`. Even if the code shown is not using jQuery we have to assume OP wants jQuery as OP specified. Part of the problem could well be that OP is not using `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
idArr = marray.map(function(row) {
    return row.id;
});
```

`row` is the current value, not the entire array. So no need for the `i`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8v7C/)

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.map()` from jquery,

```
idArr = $.map(marray, function(v,i) {
                return v.id;
        });
```

Comment: I know what is wrong with OPs code, but I'm wondering why you use jQuery instead of JavaScript.

Comment: @putvande: Before you edited the question OP was actually asking for jQuery `.map()`. Only because the code shown didn't use jQuery, doesn't mean OP is not asking for jQuery solution.

Comment: @putvande initially the question was tagged with jquery, so I just suggested doing this way.. But using plain js is best in this context.